# I Can't use COUNT and have any other code running in the file (SQL)

Tags: sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm Trying to make code where an employees are filtered by their skills, with if the employee has one or no skills, they don't come up. I got the first half done, getting them filtered by their skills, but whenever I try to add a COUNT, it doesn't work unless it's running entirely on its own!

```
Select k.employeeID, COUNT (*)
FROM EmployeeSkills_t k
GROUP BY k.employeeID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Does not want to intergrate with

```
select e.Employeename, s.skillDescription
from EmployeeSkills_t k
INNER JOIN Employee_t e ON k.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Skill_t s ON k.skillID=s.skillID 
ORDER BY e.Employeename, skillDescription
```

Comment: You could probably compute and filter the aggregate in a *cross apply*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for to join an aggregate query. Instead, starting from your existing query that lists the skills of each employee, you can do a window `count()` to compute how many skills each of them has. All that is left to do is to filter :

```
select *
from (
    select e.employeename, s.skilldescription,
        count(*) over(partition by e.employeeid) as cnt_employee_skills
    from employeeskills_t k
    inner join employee_t e on k.employeeid = e.employeeid
    inner join skill_t s on k.skillid=s.skillid 
) t
where cnt_employee_skills > 1
order by employeename, skilldescription
```

Answer (score 1):

can you just join your 2 queries together?

```
with t as (Select k.employeeID, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM EmployeeSkills_t k
GROUP BY k.employeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
select e.Employeename, s.skillDescription, cnt
from EmployeeSkills_t k
INNER JOIN Employee_t e ON k.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Skill_t s ON k.skillID=s.skillID 
INNER JOIN t on k.employeeId = t.employeeId
ORDER BY e.Employeename, skillDescription
```

Comment: Nah, It just says the t is a syntax error for me